# Semantic and logical considerations for HTML markup of property/value pair lists

Tags: html, css

I have a list of property/value pairs where properties are on the left and values on the right:

```
First Name: John
Last Name: Doe
Phone Number: (555) 555-1212
Email: johndoe@stackoverflow.com
```

My first thought was this would be a perfect opportunity to use a defined list (dl).  This article http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/definition-lists-v-tables, however, recommends against it for accessibility reasons.  Furthermore, I have a difficult time styling defined lists so they will work in IE7 ([Style DL as a table. Oh no, IE7 floats DD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702638/style-dl-as-a-table-oh-no-ie7-floats-dd)), but hopefully I can figure it out.

Another option is a table, but that just doesn't seem right.

Maybe an unordered list which contains the pairs wrapped in their own tags?

What HTML markup should I use for this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend using `<dl></dl>` if you want semantics and I have only one statement for those who care too much about IE7 and IE8. "It's 2013 update your browser." However with proper styling `<dl>` works just fine in IE7 and IE8.

Now the choice is yours. Go for the semantic and nice way or keep your website in tables so it will work for ie7 and for 2% of the users who use it. Think about it.

P.S. Don't treat `<dl>` as a `<table>` since it isn't one.

Comment: Thanks!  What I don't like about defined lists is that there is not a tag around each pair.  What about an unordered list with defined list in side it?

Comment: Since your content isn't and unordered list I don't advise you to use it, if you care about semantics. Usually when I need something to hold dt and dd all together (rare case), I create a new html element (dgroup or something), W3C validator goes crazy, but that usually does the trick. Of course you can use whatever markup you want, but only dl would be the semantic way :P.

Answer (score 2):

One has to be very careful when measuring what screen readers "do", certainly with tables and possibly with other elements. A couple of years ago I did some experiments with JAWS, and what I found surprised me. JAWS and presumably other screen readers use a secret heuristic to decide whether to treat a table as a semantic table or a layout table which takes in more factors than the markup alone. For instance the same markup may be treated as a semantic table or a layout table based on how wide the screen is into which the table is rendered. This may be a direct or an indirect effect, I couldn't tell, but either way it made no sense, but was clearly the case.

I endorse Axente Paul's answer. Write your markup to be semantic according to the best advice on semantics of the day. Leave it to the screen reader manufacturers to make the best of the information that the accessibility chain provides to them. If they don't get it right, that is an issue for the screen reader manufacturers and their users, not for markup authors.